# any character notation for php regular expression

Tags: php, regular-language

In my regex, I want to say that within the sample text, any characters are allowed, including a-z in upper and lower case, numbers and special characters.

For example, my regular expression may be checking that a document is html.  therefore:

```
"/\n<html>[]+</html>\n/"
```

i have tried []+ but it does not seem to like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[XXX]+` means any character that's between `[` and `]`, one or more than one time.

Here, you didn't put any character between `[` and `]` -- hence the problem.

If you want to say "any possible character", you can use a `.`

Note : by default, it will not match newlines ; you'll have to play with [**Pattern Modifiers**][1] if you want it to.

If you want to say any letter, you can use :

- for lower case : `[a-z]`
- for upper-case : `[A-Z]`
- for both : `[a-zA-Z]`

And, for numbers :

- `[0-9]` : any digit
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]` : any lower-case or upper-case letter, and any number.

At that point, you will probably want to take a look at :

- The [**Backslash**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.backslash.php) section of the PCRE manual
- And, especially, the `\w` meta-character, which means "any word character"

After that, when you'll begin using a regex such as

```
/.+/s
```

which should match :

- Any possible character

  - Including newlines
- One or more time

You'll see that it doesn't "stop" when you expect it too -- that's because matching is greedy, by default -- you'll have to use a `?` after the `+`, or use the `U` modifier ; see the [**Repetition**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) section, for more informations.

Well, actually, the best thing to do would be to *invest* some time, carefully reading everything in the [**PCRE Patterns**][4] section of the manual, if you want to start working with regexes ;-)

Oh, and, BTW : **using regex to *parse* HTML is a bad idea...**

It's generally much better to use a DOM Parser, such as :

- [**`DOMDocument::loadHTML`**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  I am rather new to this! :-)

I am not actually using it for html though. :-D

Comment: You're welcome :-) *(And glad to hear that, about HTML ;-) )*

Answer (score 2):

the dot `.` is the meta character for "any character"

Comment: Note that by default, the `.` does not match line breaks.

Comment: Don't forget the "s" (PCRE_DOTALL) modifier if you want it to match newlines as well.

Comment: You add the modifiers after your ending delimiter. http://fi2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php